# Alternative to 'for loops' in python which will run fast

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my python script, I have a 2d numpy array(named original_data) in which 
1) I have to find all the unique rows
2)create an empty array
3)compare all the rows in the original_data with this unique_rows, when it matches with any row of unique_rows append the rowindex of that particular row of unique values to the created new array

```
original_data = np.array([[1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1],
   [1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1],
   [1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1],
   [1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1],
   [1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1]])
y = np.ascontiguousarray(original_data).view(np.dtype((np.void, original_data.dtype.itemsize * original_data.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(y, return_index=True)
unique_rows = original_data[idx]
att = []
for i in range(original_data.shape[0]):
  for j in range(unique_rows.shape[0]):
    if(np.array_equal(original_data[i],unique_rows[j])):
        att.append(j)
        break
    else:
        continue
```

this is running good but if I consider large dataset then this for loops is not a good option as it takes so much time to run. Can anyone suggest me a good replacement for these 2 forloops which runs much faster.

Comment: Whenever I see an empty list created and then a loop appending to it, I try to come up with a list comprehension to replace it. Often a generator expression is better yet.

Comment: What kind of data is in the array? Small integers, big integers, floating point or other? Also what is the usual shape of the array?

Comment: Is there a logic behind the output `att [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`? What defines that the last rows are `0`? It is not the first occurence, it is not how often each row appears.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the desired output. How I read it is you want for all rows to see the index when a row first occurred in your original list. Am I right?

Comment: yaa att = [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], my row index is starting from 0 thats why few values are zeroes

Answer (score 1):

There's another option for `unique` that does exactly this:

```
y = np.ascontiguousarray(original_data).view(np.dtype((np.void, original_data.dtype.itemsize * original_data.shape[1])))
_, att = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
```

From numpy version 1.13 the trick with void dtype has become part of `unique`, so you could use the new `axis` keyword argument:

```
_, att = np.unique(original_data, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
```

If you need it to go faster, you might be able to calculate hashes for the rows and do the processing on those. But then taking care of hash collisions might be hard to do with numpy..

Comment: Okayy didn't know this before .. Thankyou for correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 with any such loop is to try to make it a list comprehension:

```
att = [j
   for i in range(original_data.shape[0])
   for j in range(unique_rows.shape[0])
   if np.array_equal(original_data[i], unique_rows[j])]
```

After that, re-think what you're trying to accomplish and how else it might be done. In this case, if you used the following dictionary comprehension, you'd get what you're looking for (assuming you don't need the unique rows to be ordered in the same order they were found in your original data):

```
data = [tuple(row) for row in original_data]
unique_rows = set(data)
unique_row_map = {row: i for i, row in enumerate(unique_rows)}
att = [unique_row_map[row] for row in data]
```

Comment: Awesome!! got it!! thanq so much